# Issues adding a slider to custom php template in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

trying to add a slider to a simple custom landing page using a php template. this is the code i am using:

```
 <?php
        /* Template Name: Custom Home Page */
        get_header();
    ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main_wrapper">  
        <div id="featured_area"> 
<div id="feature_slider">  
        <ul>  
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slider-1.jpg" alt="First Slide" /></a></li>  
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slider-2.jpg" alt="Second Slide" /></a></li>  
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slider-3.jpg" alt="Third Slide" /></a></li>  
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slider-4.jpg" alt="Fourth Slide" /></a></li>  
        </ul>  
    </div>  

        </div>  
        <div id="column_wrapper">  
            <div class="column">  
  <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('left_column')) : else : ?>  
        <p><strong>Widget Ready</strong></p>  
        <p>This left_column is widget ready! Add one in the admin panel.</p>  
    <?php endif; ?>     
            </div>  
            <div class="column">  
     <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('center_column')) : else : ?>  
        <p><strong>Widget Ready</strong></p>  
        <p>This center_column is widget ready! Add one in the admin panel.</p>  
    <?php endif; ?>     
            </div>  
            <div class="column">  
   <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('right_column')) : else : ?>  
        <p><strong>Widget Ready</strong></p>  
        <p>This right_column is widget ready! Add one in the admin panel.</p>  
    <?php endif; ?>       
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

slider is sliding showing only alt tag...see for yourself:http://onlinebettingguide.org/custom/
any help you could give me would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: I see you fixed the problem on your live site, was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The slider works, the code is valid, but the images do not exist.

http://onlinebettingguide.org/wp-content/themes/sportedge-parent/images/slider-1.jpg et al returns 404 error.

The images on your server have a space before the number, not hyphen. This will fix you up:

```
    <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slider 1.jpg" alt="First Slide" /></a></li>  
    <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slider 2.jpg" alt="Second Slide" /></a></li>  
    <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slider 3.jpg" alt="Third Slide" /></a></li>  
    <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slider 4.jpg" alt="Fourth Slide" /></a></li>
```